# How to fetch link from json and connect it to button?

Tags: android, json

I am working with a project and I am trying to fetch some link from a json data and I want to connect the link with a button in my recycleview so that whenever the button is clicked, it'll automatically connet to the respective websites. I gave user permission to interner in Manifest. So, How to connect it?

```
    package com.example.covidcuretemplate1;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ExampleAdapter exampleAdapter;
private ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL,false));

    exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    parseJSON();
}

private void parseJSON() {

    String url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=health&apiKey=*************************";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("articles");

                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            JSONObject article = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            if(article.isNull("description") || article.isNull("urlToImage")) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            if(article.getString("description").isEmpty() || article.getString("urlToImage").isEmpty())
                                continue;

                            String title = article.getString("title");
                            String description = article.getString("description");

                            String date = article.getString("publishedAt");
                            String imageurl = article.getString("urlToImage");

                            //How to connect this??????
                            String newsurl = article.getString("url");


                            exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imageurl,title,description,date));

                        }

                        exampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this,exampleList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(exampleAdapter);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
}
```

}

My Adapter class, Here can anybody suggest anything in the place of toast? The Toast is working fine !!!

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

public Context mcontext;
public ArrayList<ExampleItem> marrayList;

public ExampleAdapter(Context mcontext, ArrayList<ExampleItem> marrayList) {
    this.mcontext = mcontext;
    this.marrayList = marrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.card_item,parent,false);
    ExampleViewHolder exampleViewHolder = new ExampleViewHolder(view);
    return exampleViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ExampleItem examplItem = marrayList.get(position);

    String imageurl = examplItem.getMimgurl();
    String title = examplItem.getMtitle();
    String description = examplItem.getMdescription();
    String date = examplItem.getMdate();

    /////////////
    final String newsurl = examplItem.getMurl();
    ////////////


    holder.textview_title.setText(title);
    holder.textview_description.setText(description);
    holder.textview_date.setText(date);
    Glide.with(mcontext).load(imageurl).into(holder.imageview_news);

    ///////////////////////////
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             
            //////////////////////////////////NEED HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!/////////

     Toast.makeText(mcontext,newsurl,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            
            
        }
    });
    //////////////////////////

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return marrayList.size();
}

public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public ImageView imageview_news;
    public TextView textview_title;
    public TextView textview_description;
    public TextView textview_date;

    ///////////////////////////
    public Button button;
    ///////////////////////////

    public ExampleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageview_news = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageview_news);
        textview_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
        textview_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_description);
        textview_date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_date);

        /////////////////////////
        button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        ////////////////////////
    }
}
```

}

Comment: so you want to open link in browser?

Comment: where is the problem, set the link or open it?

Comment: @Niraj ya, I want to open it in browser

Comment: @Felix I can fetch the link but cant connect it to the button in recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Try to set intent for the website inside the onClickListener. Something like this:

```
 Button button= findViewById(R.id.button);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String url = "http://www.YourWebsite.com"; //insert the link you prase
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code inside `onClickListener` to open it in the browser.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(newsurl);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much man, I was working on a new context, xo I was facing some problem, this helped !

Comment: ```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(newsurl);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
mcontext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It's the same thing I wrote half an hour ago?